# BrowserMobProxy with browserstack is not intercepting the response

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browserstack, browsermob-proxy, browsermob

I am using JAVA + SELENIUM web-driver + browser mobproxy + browserstacklocal ( embeded)

```
compile 'com.browserstack:browserstack-local-java:1.0.2'
compile 'net.lightbody.bmp:browsermob-core:2.1.5'
```

Locally its working fine as I am able to intercept the api response and override the response code ( as example 200-OK to 502-BAD_GATEWAY)

However while running this test in the browserstack , its not working as seems mobproxy is not intercepting the response and overriding that. So assertion fails in the test steps. Other tests which does not depend on mobproxy are working fine in browsestack.

```
Proxy seleniumProxy = ProxyUtils.getInstance().createSeleniumProxy();
String host=seleniumProxy.getHttpProxy()
            .substring(0,seleniumProxy.getHttpProxy().indexOf(":"));
String port=seleniumProxy.getHttpProxy()
            .substring(seleniumProxy.getHttpProxy()
            .indexOf(":")+1,seleniumProxy.getHttpProxy().length());
browserStackLocalArgs.put("key", <key>);
browserStackLocalArgs.put("localIdentifier", <identifier>);
browserStackLocalArgs.put("forcelocal", "true");
browserStackLocalArgs.put("force", "true");
browserStackLocalArgs.put("forceproxy", "true");
browserStackLocalArgs.put("localProxyHost", host);
browserStackLocalArgs.put("localProxyPort", String.valueOf(port));
browserStackLocalArgs.put("--daemon", "start");
browserStackLocal.start(browserStackLocalArgs);
```

I have used both localProxyHost and -local-proxy-host but no luck. 
I am adding the set capability for the browserstack as well.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
browserStackCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
```

While doing ps -ef | grep browserstack it returns me

```
505   921     1   0  6:33pm ??         0:00.86 /Users/ITAS4/.browserstack/BrowserStackLocal -d start sqfXJPx2Hpyp4L -forceproxy -localIdentifier browserstack_local_machine -force -localProxyPort 49676 ---daemon start -forcelocal -localProxyHost CHISIMAC0123.local -daemonInstance

505   943   921   0  6:33pm ??         0:02.29 /Users/ITAS4/.browserstack/BrowserStackLocal sqfXJPx2Hpyp4L -forceproxy -localIdentifier browserstack_local_machine-browserstack-fork-0 -localProxyPort 49676 ---daemon start -forcelocal -localProxyHost CHISIMAC0123.local -daemonInstance

505   944   921   0  6:33pm ??         0:00.79 /Users/ITAS4/.browserstack/BrowserStackLocal sqfXJPx2Hpyp4L -forceproxy -localIdentifier browserstack_local_machine-browserstack-fork-1 -localProxyPort 49676 ---daemon start -forcelocal -localProxyHost CHISIMAC0123.local -daemonInstance

505   945   921   0  6:33pm ??         0:00.80 /Users/ITAS4/.browserstack/BrowserStackLocal sqfXJPx2Hpyp4L -forceproxy -localIdentifier browserstack_local_machine-browserstack-fork-2 -localProxyPort 49676 ---daemon start -forcelocal -localProxyHost CHISIMAC0123.local -daemonInstance

505   946   921   0  6:33pm ??         0:00.79 /Users/ITAS4/.browserstack/BrowserStackLocal sqfXJPx2Hpyp4L -forceproxy -localIdentifier browserstack_local_machine-browserstack-fork-3 -localProxyPort 49676 ---daemon start -forcelocal -localProxyHost CHISIMAC0123.local -daemonInstance

505   947   921   0  6:33pm ??         0:00.80 /Users/ITAS4/.browserstack/BrowserStackLocal sqfXJPx2Hpyp4L -forceproxy -localIdentifier browserstack_local_machine-browserstack-fork-4 -localProxyPort 49676 ---daemon start -forcelocal -localProxyHost CHISIMAC0123.local -daemonInstance
```

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Your parameters looks correct, what is output in ps -ef of BrowserStackLocal instance. Need the instance parameter here.

Comment: @BipulJain I have added the output of ps -ef | grep browserstack in the description section.

Comment: Can you try remove browserStackLocalArgs.put("--daemon", "start"); from the args and also remove/mask the key in the output shown here.

Comment: The key I have mentioned here is wrong one. I have already deleted few characters from the original string :)

Comment: No luck after removing the browserStackLocalArgs.put("--daemon", "start")..

Comment: working fine now after using the correct port

Comment: cool i missed an accepted answer. :)